# Voltage with zero current?

Tags: voltage

In this incomplete circuit there voltage of V1 equals 20V yet the current is 0, since it's an "open" circuit correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFqJo1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even when putting voltage sources in series might they increase their total voltage at I = 0?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs1fGB.png)</sup>

Possibly having V = 0, even in an open circuit like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx29qp.png)</sup>

Comment: Yes, right on all counts.

Comment: I'm just flagging this as off-topic because there's no option for "the answer isn't the least bit interesting".

Comment: Note that you can't actually measure the voltage unless *some* current flows; even a high-quality DMM has a non-infinite impedance (typically 10M\$\Omega\$).

Comment: Can voltage exist without current? That is mostly the question.

Comment: Always consider cables (and conductors) as resistors. The value you can calculate by the well known equation!

Comment: As stated below, voltage must always be measured between two points.  You don't explicitly indicate what the other point is above.

Comment: @Key: it absolutely can, the same way pressure can exist without flow, force can exist without motion, etc.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Sure you can. All you need to do is connect the voltage you want to measure to one side of a null detector (a femtoammeter, say) and a voltage source to the other end, then adjust the voltage source for zero current through the null detector. Then measure the source voltage and you're done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot say the voltage is 20V or whatever at a given point without having a reference point (usually assumed to be ground or whatever).

In all these case, there is no grounded point, so calling out a voltage makes no sense at all.

If you try to simulate this in SPICE or build it for real, the results will be similar (actually SPICE will choke, and you'll have a meter with the black lead floating in the air).

Comment: What I mean by this question is that some power supplies can have voltage set to a certain value while as current is zero because it's an open circuit. Likewise, simple diagrams that show the existence of voltage without current. I'm not sure how ground can relate to such circuits? **Can there be a ground in an open circuit?**

Comment: Yes, there can be, but there does not have to be. There need to be **two** points to define a voltage. If you charge a capacitor and throw it up in the air it will have a voltage across it (from one terminal to the other) but neither will be grounded. If you ground one terminal, then the voltage will not change (ideally).

Comment: This question was basically asking something else, **can voltage exist in a circuit without current?**

Comment: A voltage can exist across two points without current. I'll leave the epistemological (or is it ontological?) arguments over whether it's a "circuit" without current flowing to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

> This question was basically asking something else, can voltage exist
>   in a circuit without current?

Of course.  For example, and in the ideal circuit context, place a capacitor across your voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqN6W7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then, there is a constant voltage across the capacitor which you can measure with a voltmeter.

But the current through the capacitor, which is proportional to the rate of change of the voltage across, is *zero*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right on all counts.

(Only answering so that the question won't keep being brought back to the front page)